# How to add breakpoints to a Swiper element?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

```
<swiper-container
    space-between={10}
    slides-per-view="1"
    loop="true"
    autoplay="true"
    speed="400"
    style={swiperContainerStyle}
    grab-cursor="true"
    breakpoints={{
      640: {
        slidesPerView: 2
      },
      768: {
        slidesPerView: 4
      },
      1024: {
        slidesPerView: 5
      }
    }}
  >
```

The breakpoint code here works for older version of Swiper where I use a Swiper component instead of Swiper element. I have checked the docs already but can't find any example syntax for the adding breakpoints. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read https://swiperjs.com/element#parameters-as-props

Comment: The example there shows how to add parameters inside a script tag. I'm trying to add parameters inline.

Comment: But also it states at the start ***"In some more complex cases when we have more complex parameters objects (like with breakpoints), we can pass all parameters as HTMLElement properties."*** And the docs about [Usage with React](https://swiperjs.com/element#usage-with-react) state "***React doesn't fully supports web components yet (as for version 18). So the usage is basically the same as in HTML***"

Answer (score 1):

I'd same issue today but with Swiper Element.It doesn't seem to have that option yet ,what you can do is use js configs the way they did it in their docs :

const swiperEl = document.querySelector('.favourites-slider');

```
Object.assign(swiperEl, {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  spaceBetween: 5, 
 
  breakpoints: {
    640: {
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 10,
    },
    768: {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 10,
    },
    1024: {
      slidesPerView: 5,  
      spaceBetween: 20,
    },
  },
});
swiperEl.initialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add in one line structure like this:

```
breakpoints="{&quot;768&quot;:{&quot;slidesPerView&quot;:2},&quot;1024&quot;:{&quot;slidesPerView&quot;:3}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to pass parameters to your swiper-container using useRef hook. You can find the full guide in the following article.

https://dev.to/ivadyhabimana/customizing-swiperjs-prevnext-arrow-buttons-and-pagination-bullets-in-react-3gkh

So what I've done is basically following and it works for me:

```
const SearchPrograms = () => {
  const swiperRef = useRef<any>(null);

  const { isFetching } = useGetProgramsWithProvidersAndCartDataQuery({
    status: Status[0],
  });

  const programs = useAppSelector((state) =>
    searchPrograms(state.managerSearchCourses)
  );

  const filteredPrograms = useAppSelector((state) =>
    searchProgramsFiltered(state.managerSearchCourses)
  );

  const hasFilterQuery = useAppSelector((state) =>
    noFilterQuery(state.managerSearchCourses)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (swiperRef?.current) {
      const swiperContainer = swiperRef?.current;

      const params = {
        navigation: true,
        breakpoints: {
          1040: {
            slidesPerView: 2.8,
          },
          1200: {
            slidesPerView: 3.8,
          },
          1366: {
            slidesPerView: 3.8,
          },
          1600: {
            slidesPerView: 5.8,
          },
        },
      };

      Object.assign(swiperContainer, params);

      swiperContainer.initialize();
    }
  }, [programs]);

  const data = hasFilterQuery ? programs : filteredPrograms;

  const memoizedData = useMemo(() => {
    return data;
  }, [data]);

  return isFetching ? (
    <CenteredContainer>
      <CircularProgress />
    </CenteredContainer>
  ) : (
    <>
      <ProgramsContainer
        component="section"
        sx={{ position: "relative" }}
      >
        {!memoizedData?.length ? (
          <Typography
            sx={{ textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "700", fontSize: "1.6rem" }}
          >
            No matches found
          </Typography>
        ) : (
          <>
            <ResponsiveContainer
              container
              spacing={{ laptop: 2, tablet: 2, mobile: 2 }}
              columns={{ tablet: 6, laptop: 66 }}
            >
              <swiper-container
                ref={swiperRef}
                // @ts-ignore
                class="program-slider"
              >
                {memoizedData.map((program) => (
                  <swiper-slide
                    // @ts-ignore
                    class="slider-card"
                    key={program.id}
                  >
                    <ProgramGridContainer
                      mobile={12}
                      tablet={6}
                      laptop={12}
                    >
                      <PurchaseCard program={program} />
                    </ProgramGridContainer>
                  </swiper-slide>
                ))}
              </swiper-container>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
          </>
        )}

        <Box sx={{ height: "100%" }}></Box>
      </ProgramsContainer>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchPrograms;
```